# Can MF/IMFMediaSession intelligently support device insertion and removal?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

- I have a Win7 machine, when the headset is not plugged in, the taskbar sees "unavailable speaker icon", and run [Media Session Playback Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-session-playback-example) This program will trigger an error in the function CPlayer:: HandleEvent，hrStatus = MF_E_CANNOT_CREATE_SINK when meType = MESessionTopologySet. The MFTrace prompt is:

  ...

  8764,239C 04: 18: 40.42515 CMFMediaSessionDetours :: EndGetEvent @ 0429FB78 Met = 101  MESessionTopologySet, value @ 040FF4F8, failed HrStatus = C00D36FA **MF_E_CANNOT_CREATE_SINK**,

  ...

  8764,239C 04: 18: 40.42524 CTopologyHelpers :: TraceNode @ Node 1 @ 04112FE8 ID: 223C00000002, 1 inputs, 0 outputs, type 0, MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID = {D23E6476-B104-4707-81CB-E1CA19A07016}; MF_TOPONODE_NOTOM_DETO_DEE_STRE 0; MF_TOPONODE_ERRORCODE = **MF_E_NO_AUDIO_PLAYBACK_DEVICE**

  ...
- [MF SimplePlay](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/SimplePlay) and [MFPlayer2](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFPlayer2) these also do not support dynamic insertion and removal, that is, if there is no audio render device at the beginning of the playback, even if the device is plugged in immediately, there is no sound.
- I want to know if there is a simple way to automatically support device insertion and removal??

  1. By indirectly or directly adjusting the IMFMediaSession settings, so that the program can
     automatically adapt: ​​no matter whether the default device exists, it can work normally?
  2. Or do I have to program myself to implement
     the IMMNotificationClient interface and rebuild the whole IMFMediaSession when audio render device insertion?
  3. Or is there a similar IMFPresentationDescriptor :: DeselectStream /
     MFCreateAudioRendererActivate-ConnectOutput method to dynamically delete or add node?
  4. Or do I implement custom IMFMediaSink myself to manage and render data?

Comment: You may need to handle WM_DEVICECHANGE message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange
Also check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/detecting-media-insertion-or-removal